# How do you properly validate an email domain?

Tags: validation, email, dns, smtp, rfc

I have encountered a problem today, my mail server failed a domain name validation and refused to accept the email because the domain in question has no A record. It has SOA, NS, TXT and MX records only.

Since many domains do not have MX my server like many others are programmed to look for an A record when validating. The back-up MX look-up if A fail was disabled thus it resulted in failure.

I have now enabled the redundancy but this particular incident leaves me puzzled.

**Aren't domains supposed to have an A record?**

**How should a proper email domain validation of a SMTP server check and validate a domain?**

I have been looking for the RFC regulation about this but I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You are `sending` mail from this mail server, not `receiving` mail at this mail server, correct?  If so, then you do not need an MX record that points to this machine, but there are a few things that you need to setup with regard to DNS for this machine.  This mail server should have a fully qualified hostname (like smtp.yourdomain.tld) and there should be an A record for this hostname that points to this mail server's IP address.  Furthermore, there should be a PTR record for the IP, that reverses back to the mail server's hostname.  The mail server should also identify itself to other mail servers (in the HELO or EHLO command) using this hostname.

The reason for this is not based on anything that you'll find in RFC.  Instead, this is how spam filters attempt to distinguish real mail servers from servers that are used only to send spam.  The thinking is that real mail servers will pass the above forward and reverse DNS tests, whereas machines that have been taken over as bots or zombies would not (because even though an attacker has control over a botted machine, he cannot control the DNS for that machine).

In the DNS is not setup correctly for an outbound mail server, then chances are that most mail from that server will be flagged as spam on the receiving end.

Comment: I am receiving. If I was sending I would have had the A record.

Comment: I have **Forward Confirmed Reverse DNS** on my mail server.